# Changing resource folder in accordance to the size of screen in Cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm using Xcode IDE and Cocos2dx for developing multi platform game.
i have just started development and 'm stuccoed at one place. I want to change the resource folder in accordance to the size of the screen.

```
CCSize screenSize = pEGLView->getFrameSize();
       CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->setDesignResolutionSize(768, 1024,
       kResolutionExactFit);
       if (screenSize.width > 768) {

          CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->setResourceDirectory("hd");

          pDirector->setContentScaleFactor(2);
      } else {

          CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->setResourceDirectory("sd");

          pDirector->setContentScaleFactor(1);
       }
```

but since the setResourceDirectory() is deprecated i can use any other method. I tried using setSearchPaths() but its giving errors. please let me know if anyone have the same thing working. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

okay, since `setDesignResolutionSize()` is deprecated we need to use `setSearchPaths()`
you can have something like this, Its working in my case:

```
    CCSize screenSize = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->getFrameSize();    
    CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->setDesignResolutionSize(768, 1024,
                                                           kResolutionExactFit);
     std::vector<std::string> searchPaths;

         if (screenSize.width > 768) {
             searchPaths.push_back("hd");
             CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->setSearchPaths(searchPaths);        
             pDirector->setContentScaleFactor(2);
         }else{
             searchPaths.push_back("sd");
             CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->setSearchPaths(searchPaths);
             pDirector->setContentScaleFactor(1);
         }
```

Comment: i have got issues with std::string searchPath;